# Pinescript HTF condition not displaying on LTF correctly

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to create levels on lower timeframes based on higher timeframe conditional candles using their open or close, so in this case the H4 candle opens below the H4 9 EMA then close above colouring the candle and creating the condition etc.

Displays as expected on H4 but when go to LTF no idea what's going on. Found the line drawing script from looking around so unsure if issue lies there or with the security request - please help!

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="MBFX H4 Booster Levels", shorttitle="MBFX H4 Booster Levels", overlay=true)


//Input
showEMA1 = input(true, title="Show EMA1")
src1 = input(close, title="Source EMA1")
EMA_tf = input(defval='240', title="Timeframe EMA1")
length1 = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length EMA1")
HTF_tf = input(defval='240', title="Timeframe")

//MTF EMA
EMA1 = ta.ema(src1,length1)
EMAMTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, EMA_tf, EMA1, barmerge.gaps_on)
plot(EMAMTF, "EMA1", color=#ffffff, display = showEMA1 ? display.all : display.none)

//Condition
rocup =  open < EMAMTF and  close > EMAMTF 
rocdwn = open > EMAMTF and close < EMAMTF 

//Build HTF Condition Bars
rocupD1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HTF_tf, rocup, barmerge.gaps_on)
rocdnD1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HTF_tf, rocdwn, barmerge.gaps_on)

c_barColor1 = rocup ? color.new(#4d42e8, 0) : rocdwn ? color.new(#ff9ff1, 11) : na
barcolor(c_barColor1) 

// Draw lines from HTF condition candles open and close
int MAX_LINES_COUNT1 = 500
int linesToKeepInput1 = input.int(2, minval = 1, maxval = MAX_LINES_COUNT1,title="Max lines back")
int Extender1 = input.int(25, minval = 1, maxval = MAX_LINES_COUNT1, title="Extend lines")

//Draws line from close of HTF candle
if rocupD1 or rocdnD1
    color lineColor = rocupD1 ? color.new(#41ec50, 0) : color.new(#ffffff, 0)
    line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index+1, close, color = lineColor, width = 1)
// Once the new line is created, delete the oldest one if we have too many.
   if array.size(line.all) > linesToKeepInput1
     line.delete(array.get(line.all, 0))
     int(na)
else
    // Extend all visible lines.
    int lineNo = 0
    while lineNo < array.size(line.all)
        line.set_x2(array.get(line.all, lineNo), bar_index + Extender1)
        lineNo += 1
    int(na)

//Draws line from open of HTF candle
if rocupD1 or rocdnD1
    color lineColor = rocupD1 ? color.new(#ff1e00, 0) : color.new(#501547, 0)
    line.new(bar_index, open, bar_index+1, open, color = lineColor, width = 1)
    // Once the new line is created, delete the oldest one if we have too many.
    if array.size(line.all) > linesToKeepInput1
        line.delete(array.get(line.all, 0))
    int(na)
else
    // Extend all visible lines.
    int lineNo = 0
    while lineNo < array.size(line.all)
        line.set_x2(array.get(line.all, lineNo), bar_index + Extender1)
        lineNo += 1
    int(na)
```

[Correct display on H4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5ImC.png)

[view on 30min as example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTfbk.png)

[Should look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o3L5a.png)

Have also recoded as below from https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/concepts/Lines_and_boxes.html without lookback but still same issue.

```
    //@version=5
indicator(title="MBFX H4 Booster Levels", shorttitle="MBFX H4 Booster Levels", overlay=true)


//Input
showEMA1 = input(true, title="Show EMA1")
src1 = input(close, title="Source EMA1")
EMA_tf = input(defval='240', title="Timeframe EMA1")
length1 = input.int(9, minval=1, title="Length EMA1")


//MTF EMA
EMA1 = ta.ema(src1,length1)
EMAMTF = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, EMA_tf, EMA1, barmerge.gaps_on)
plot(EMAMTF, "EMA1", color=#ffffff, display = showEMA1 ? display.all : display.none)

//Condition
rocup =  ta.crossover(close, EMAMTF) and  open < EMAMTF 
//rocdwn = open > EMAMTF and close < EMAMTF 

string tfInput = input.timeframe("240", "Timeframe")
// Initialize variables on bar zero only, so they preserve their values across bars.
var hi = float(na)
var lo = float(na)
var line hiLine = na
var line loLine = na
var box hiLoBox = na
// Detect changes in timeframe.
bool newTF = ta.change(time(tfInput))

if newTF and rocup
    // New bar in higher timeframe; reset values and create new lines and box.
    hi := close
    lo := open
    hiLine := line.new(bar_index, hi, bar_index, hi, color = color.green, width = 2)
    loLine := line.new(bar_index, lo, bar_index, lo, color = color.red, width = 2)
// hiLoBox := box.new(bar_index - 1, hi, bar_index, lo, border_color = na, bgcolor = color.silver)
    int(na)
else
    // On other bars, extend the right coordinate of lines and box.
    line.set_x2(hiLine, bar_index)
    line.set_x2(loLine, bar_index)
// box.set_right(hiLoBox, bar_index)
    
c_barColor1 = rocup ? color.new(#4d42e8, 0) : na
barcolor(c_barColor1)
```

Comment: Are you able to provide screengrabs of expected at current behaviour?

Comment: have added above thanks